# ACl : How to reduce if else check while fetching data from database

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, acl

I am currently working on a system where i have to fetch records permission wise.

Suppose we have a module called Clients where we can manage clients information and assign a client to a user.

Suppose we have users like:

1. Admin with permission manage.all.clients (Can add/edit/delete/view all clients)
2. Manager with permission manage.assigned.clients (Can view/edit assigned clients)
3. Counsellors with permission view.all.clients (Can view all clients)

So, How am i doing right now ?

```
<?php 
class ClientRepositoryinterface {
    public function getAllClients();
    public function getAssignedClients(User $user);
    public function getPaginatedClients();
    public function getPaginatedAssignedClients(User $user);
}
class ClientService {
    public function __constructor(ClientRepositoryInterface $clientRepository, LoggedInUser $user);
    public function getClients()
    {
        if($this->user->can('manage.all.clients','view.client.information'))
        {
            return $this->clientRepository->getAllClients();
        }
        if($this->user->can('manage.assigned.clients'))
        {
            return $this->clientRepository->getAssignedCliets($this->user);
        }
        return [];
    }
    public function getPaginatedClients()
    {
        if($this->user->can('manage.all.clients','view.client.information')){
            return $this->clientRepository->getPaginatedClients();
        }
        if($this->user->can('manage.assigned.clients')){
            return $this->clientRepository->getPaginatedAssignedClients($this->user);
        }
        return [];
    }
}
```

So, What's the problem with this code ?

1. I am doing same check again and again which fetching records from database.
2. Code Duplication
3. If we add a new permission to a user we have to add another if condition to all the methods and so on...

**So, Is there any other solution we can implement to solve this problem ?**